# Python module works only inside function

Tags: python-3.x

```
# program saved as wolgui.py
from tkinter import *
Window = Tk()
Window.title("WolframAlpha")
Window.geometry("540x590")

'''menu = Menu(Window)
item = Menu(menu)
item.add_command(label='New')
menu.add_cascade(label='Execute once more', menu=item)
Window.config(menu=menu)'''
lbl = Label(Window, text = "Ask WolframAlpha")
lbl.grid()
txt = Entry(Window, width=10)
txt.grid(column =1, row =0)



def click():
    resu =  Entry(Window,bd=5)
    #Window.mainloop()
    import wolframalpha
    client = wolframalpha.Client('YOUR_CLIENT_ID')
    result = client.query(resu)
    output = next(result.results).text
    

# button widget with blue color text inside
# Set Button.grid
btn = Button(Window, text = "Click me for the answer" ,fg = "blue",command=click)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

lbl2 = Label(Window, text = "Answer: ")
lbl2.grid()
txt2 = Entry(output, width=10)
txt2.grid(column =1, row =0)
lbl2.grid()


Window.mainloop()
```

Why do i get this traceback ??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wolgui.py", line 38, in <module>
    txt2 = Entry(output, width=10)
NameError: name 'output' is not defined

***Repl Closed***
```

I thought i had imported the function already -
So should i rewrite/import it again ?? Or is it an indentation issue??
Forgive me for my ignorance- I'm not too prolific in Python ...

Comment: This issue is related to namespace. The `output` object is defined inside the function `click()` and therefore only available to the function namespace, but not to the global namespace outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl2 = Label(Window, text = "Answer: ")
lbl2.grid()
txt2 = Entry(output, width=10)
txt2.grid(column =1, row =0)
lbl2.grid()
```

I think your problem will be solved if you put this structure at the bottom of the function. The problem is that the 'output' variable you define in the function will not be defined unless the function is executed. Because you call this variable during the first run, you encounter an error.

Answer (score 0):

> txt2 = Entry(output, width=10)
>
> NameError: name 'output' is not  defined.

You have typo error.

The problem can be fixed.

Change this:

```
txt2 = Entry(output, ...
```

to

```
txt2 = Entry(Window, ...
```